# Does JavaAssist has something like visitInvokeDynamicInsn in ASM

Tags: lambda, java-bytecode-asm, javassist, invokedynamic

I want to add some code into all my project files with JavaAssist. And i will use the params of each method. But I found when using lambda,it generated a new method in class and the params of original method will be changed finally. So Does JavaAssist has something like visitInvokeDynamicInsn method in MethodVisitor in ASM,that I can get the original owner, params and name of method? thx.

Comment: It supports iterating over the code and it understands the invokedynamic instruction, but it doesn’t work like ASM. If we want to visit like with ASM, why don’t you use ASM?

Comment: I am learning JavaAssist and I want to implement functions in my project as ASM does.  How does javaassist understands the invokedynamic instruction? Is there a method or API?  Thank you very much.

Comment: Did you look at how you can use Javassist to study the bytecode instructions in general? The handling of invokedynamic is not different.

Comment: ASM has a “visitInvokeDynamicInsn” method in MethodVisitor , when the project runs invokedynamic instructionv,  I can find many information like original params and name of the method in it, because lambda will generates a new method. So I just want to find that is there a method or sth in Javaassist.

Comment: You said, “I am learning JavaAssist”. You don’t lean it by looking what ASM does. There are tutorials out there.

Comment: The question suddenly occured to me when learning.Thanks anyway.

Comment: For completeness: [5.3 Traversing a method body on the tutorial](http://www.javassist.org/tutorial/tutorial3.html#traverse) and [the `CodeIterator` class](http://www.javassist.org/html/javassist/bytecode/CodeIterator.html), and [the `Opcode.INVOKEDYNAMIC`constant](http://www.javassist.org/html/javassist/bytecode/Opcode.html#INVOKEDYNAMIC).